# Creating a Nuget package with Cake and packing only dlls

Tags: nuget, cakebuild

When I create a nuget package from the command prompt through `myPath\nuget.exe pack -Prop Configuration=Release` my nuget package contains the DLL and nothing else; like I want it to.

When I create a Nuget package with Cake, every file in the project folder is included.
How can I get a Cake Nuget to only include my dll? to behave like the command prompt.

---

In file `build.cake` I have

```
Task("Package")
    .Does(() =>{
        NuGetPack("../CompulsoryCow/CompulsoryCow.nuspec", new NuGetPackSettings{
            Id = "CompulsoryCow",
            Authors = new []{ "LosManos" }, 
            Version = "1.0.0", 
            Description = "TBD", 
            Verbosity = NuGetVerbosity.Detailed,
        }
    );
});
```

My `CompulsoryCow.nuspec` file, that works with `nuget.exe pack`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>$id$</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <title>$title$</title>
    <authors>$author$</authors>
    <owners>$author$</owners>
    <licenseUrl>https://raw.githubusercontent.com/LosManos/CompulsoryCow/master/License.txt</licenseUrl>
    <projectUrl>https://github.com/LosManos/CompulsoryCow</projectUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>$description$</description>
    <summary>...</summary>
    <releaseNotes>...</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>LGPLv3+NoEvil.</copyright>
    <repository type="git" url="https://github.com/LosManos/CompulsoryCow" />
  </metadata>
</package>
```

---

**Update:**

I added `BasePath` to the `NuGetPackSettings` to point at the `..bin/release` folder where I have the DLL and PDB. It packs some more files but I suppose that is well behaved.

Output:

```
Added file '[Content_Types].xml'.
Added file '_rels/.rels'.
Added file 'CompulsoryCow.dll'.
Added file 'CompulsoryCow.nuspec'.
Added file 'CompulsoryCow.pdb'.
Added file 'package/services/metadata/core-properties/3a1990a4516a46118d81f4bd5961a767.psmdcp'.
```

Comment: I think this will likely be due to the current working directory that both nuget and Cake are working from. Can you confirm when you run nuget directly if you navigate into a particular folder? Can you also show the contents of the nuspec file? Particularly the files section?

Comment: @GaryEwanPark I will look into the folder tip. I updated the Q with my nuspec file. What "files section" are you referring to. I find nothing suck in the [spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/nuget/tools/cli-ref-pack).

Comment: I am referring to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#files which can be implemented for example here: https://github.com/cake-contrib/Cake.Gem/blob/develop/nuspec/nuget/Cake.Gem.nuspec#L18 without explicitly specifying what files you want to end up in the nupkg, all the files in the current folder will be added into the package.

Comment: @LosManos You may create an answer on your own with details and accept it (instead of "Update")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switched to use `CompulsoryCow.csproj` instead and then it behaves like when invoked from the command prompt. The DLL is packed but not the PDB.
On a side note it picks up Id, Authors, Version and Description from the nugetspec file; something it did not do when i used `CompulsoryCow.nuspec`.

```
Added file '[Content_Types].xml'.
Added file '_rels/.rels'.
Added file 'CompulsoryCow.nuspec'.
Added file 'lib/net40-client/CompulsoryCow.dll'.
Added file 'package/services/metadata/core-properties/c4d7ab4804fb417e8e5f9fa4d0062c74.psmdcp'.
```